# How can I change color efficiently for right/wrong characters in a typing speed test?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, colors

I was doing an exercise involving a typing speed test. I added a color palette that makes the **whole** text green if the character matches the test text and red if it does not match.

If I wanted individual characters to change though, all the ways I can think of going about this seem quite tedious. I've tried creating individual `span` tags every time a character is entered and assigning them to the array value of the text string but haven't been able to get it to work. Is there a more efficient way to do this or is my current method the "best" way to go about it?

I would much more prefer a general path to solve this as opposed to someone just writing out a complete solution so I can write it out on my own please.

```js
const testWrapper = document.querySelector(".test-wrapper");
const testArea = document.querySelector("#test-area");
const originText = document.querySelector("#origin-text p").innerHTML;
const resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
const theTimer = document.querySelector(".timer");
var interval;
var timer = [0,0,0,0];
var timerRunning = false;

// Add leading zero to numbers 9 or below (purely for aesthetics):
function leadingZero(time) {
 if (time <= 9) {
  time = "0" + time;
 }
 return time;
}

// Run a standard minute/second/hundredths timer:
function runTimer() {
 let currentTime = leadingZero(timer[0]) + ":" + leadingZero(timer[1]) + ":" + leadingZero(timer[2]);
 theTimer.innerHTML = currentTime;
 timer[3]++;
 
 timer[0] = Math.floor((timer[3]/100)/60);
 timer[1] = Math.floor((timer[3]/100) - (timer[0] * 60));
 timer[2] = Math.floor(timer[3] - (timer[1] * 100) - (timer[0] * 6000));
}

// Match the text entered with the provided text on the page:
function spellCheck() {
 let textEntered = testArea.value;
 let originTextMatch = originText.substring(0,textEntered.length);
 if (textEntered == originText) {
  testWrapper.style.borderColor = "#429890";
  clearInterval(interval);
 } else {
  if (textEntered == originTextMatch) {
   testWrapper.style.borderColor = "#65ccf3";
   testArea.style.color = "#00B400";
  } else {
   testWrapper.style.borderColor = "#e95d0f";
   testArea.style.color = "#FF0000"
  }
 }
}

// Start the timer:
function start() {
 let textEnteredLength = testArea.value.length;
 if(textEnteredLength === 0 && !timerRunning) {
  timerRunning = true;
  interval = setInterval(runTimer, 10);
 }
}

// Reset everything:
function reset(){
 timer = [0,0,0,0];
 theTimer.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
 clearInterval(interval);
 testArea.value = "";
 timerRunning = false;
 console.log("The reset button has been pressed.");
}

// Event listeners for keyboard input and the reset button:
testArea.addEventListener("keypress", start, false);
testArea.addEventListener("keyup", spellCheck, false);
resetButton.addEventListener("click", reset, false);
```

```css
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Typography
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
 clear: both;
}

p {
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

b,
strong {
 font-weight: bold;
}

dfn,
cite,
em,
i {
 font-style: italic;
}

blockquote {
 margin: 0 1.5em;
}

address {
 margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

pre {
 background: #eee;
 font-family: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 line-height: 1.6;
 margin-bottom: 1.6em;
 max-width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 padding: 1.6em;
}

code,
kbd,
tt,
var {
 font: 15px Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
}

abbr,
acronym {
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
 cursor: help;
}

mark,
ins {
 background: #fff9c0;
 text-decoration: none;
}

sup,
sub {
 font-size: 75%;
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
 bottom: 1ex;
}

sub {
 top: .5ex;
}

small {
 font-size: 75%;
}

big {
 font-size: 125%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Layout
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.masthead {
    padding: 1em 2em;
    background-color: #0D1B2E;
    color: white;
}

.masthead h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.intro {
    padding: 2em 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #429890;
}


.intro p,
.test-area {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 550px;
}

.test-area {
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    padding: 0 2em;
}

.test-wrapper {
    border: 10px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#origin-text {
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 1em 1em 0;
    background-color: #ededed;
}

#origin-text p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.test-wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.test-wrapper textarea {
    flex: 1;
}

.meta {
    margin-top: 1em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.timer {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#reset {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #E95D0F;
    background: white ;
    border: 10px solid #E95D0F;
}

#reset:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #E95D0F;
}
```

```html
    <header class="masthead">
        <h1>Test Your Typing Speed</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
        <article class="intro">
            <p>This is a typing test. Your goal is to duplicate the provided text, EXACTLY, in the field below. The timer starts when you start typing, and only stops when you match this text exactly. Good Luck!</p>
        </article><!-- .intro -->
        <section class="test-area">
            <div id="origin-text">
                <p>The text to test.</p>
            </div><!-- #origin-text -->

            <div class="test-wrapper">
                <textarea id="test-area" name="textarea" rows="6" placeholder="The clock starts when you start typing."></textarea>
            </div><!-- .test-wrapper -->

            <div class="meta">
                <section id="clock">
                    <div class="timer">00:00:00</div>
                </section>

                <button id="reset">Start over</button>
            </div><!-- .meta -->
        </section><!-- .test-area -->
    </main>
```

Comment: *"seem quite tedious"* Tedious isn't exactly a performance problem. Is there actually a performance problem (e.g. lag while typing) in your code?

Comment: When I say "tedious" I mean that as in I merely mean that I feel like I may be making it more complicated than it could be. As I said, I could make a function that creates new spans every single time for each new character entered and manipulate the attributes for it and then delete it every backspace, etc. But as I was writing it out, it just felt way to clunky. I know that is bound to happen sometimes with coding but I was just wondering if there was a better method.

Comment: But you can't do multicolored text in a regular `textbox`, you'd have to fake it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700433/ideas-for-multicolored-textbox) for example.

Comment: @MattBurland Well I'm just looking to change the characters themselves a very simple example being https://jsfiddle.net/4bfb28pb/

But I'll read up on the topic you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is your question, I would say to use an MVVM framework such as KnockoutJS or Angular, then it's really easy to determine differences and keeps the code real clean.

I'd split the text to copy into two, side by side: 
1. Text typed | 2. Text to copy

With a separate box to type into.

You would subtract what you type upon key press, probably bassed on string length, from 2.text to copy, and put it into 1.text typed.

Use a calculated method to determine if it matched, and set the class on 1.text typed accordingly.